# Poisson Distribution question on the odds of something happening if the time interval changes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

**Given an event X that has a 68% chance of happening within 3 years, what are the odds of that event happening each year?**

I tried to solve this using a Poisson Distribution but I am confused how my time interval factors into the equation.

I used the equation **((e ^ -lambda) * (lambda ^ # of successes)) / (# of successes)!** = P(x)
where lambda represents the expected number of successes.

Comment: If you assume that the number of events happening in a $t$-years period $N(t)$ follow a Poisson process, then $N(t) \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$. If the first condition given means the event happen at least once in $3$ years is $68\%$, then you can try to solve the $\lambda$ by setting $1 - e^{-3\lambda} = 68\%$, and then later compute the required probability.

Comment: On current state of your question we do not know whether we can use Poisson (as we need to have assumption that consequtive events happen with exponential frequency).
Do you have any assumptions regarding distribution of happening (e.g. inter-happening times are exponential, or uniform)?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other information aside from the fact that there is a 68% chance of an event happening within 3 years. Let's just say it's safe to assume it's not a uniform distribution.

Comment: Confusingly stated, and your 'equation' is not an equation: **Maybe** this R code (following @BGM) gives correct answer: `lam = -log(.32)/3; 1 - dpois(0, lam)` returns 0.3160096, where `dpois` is Poisson PDF.